# pre html tag giving different output in Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, pre

I've been working on pre html tag and came across an issue while switching from Bootstrap 3 to Bootstrap 4.

If I run the this code using Bootstrap 3.3.7,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>
<title>Pre html tag sample</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<body>
This is a normal content
<pre>Hello there. 
This is a content inside the pre html tag test.
This is a pre html tag test.
</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

I get the following output

[image]

If I run the this code using Bootstrap 4.5.2,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>
<title>Pre html tag sample</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<body>
This is a normal content
<pre>Hello there. 
This is a content inside the pre html tag test.
This is a pre html tag test.
</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

I get the following output

[image]

I want to get the same pre html tag output of Bootstrap 3 (the first screenshot) using the Bootstrap 4. How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

Both versions look similar in appearance but I guess it's the **padding** that is bothering you ?
If we compare both style sheets we can indeed see differences in the way the tag is styled.
In the 3.3.7 version there is this:

```
pre{display:block;padding:9.5px;margin:0 0 10px;font-size:13px;line-height:1.42857143;color:#333;word-break:break-all;word-wrap:break-word;background-color:#f5f5f5;border:1px solid #ccc;border-radius:4px}
```

In 4.5.2 padding seems to be missing but it's possible that I missed something as I only had a cursory look:

```
pre{display:block;font-size:87.5%;color:#212529}
```

Note that there are few more relevant styles like:

```
code,kbd,pre,samp{font-family:monospace,monospace;font-size:1em}
```

I have only singled out the one I think is important.

Seeing that you use a CDN to retrieve the style sheets you could `override` some tags with a custom style sheet hosted on your site. For example redefine the pre tag like this:

```
pre {
display:block;
padding:9.5px;
font-size:87.5%;
color:#212529
}
```

And you add your style sheet **after** the Bootstrap import like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://yoursite.com/custom.css">
```

Note that the margins are also different between both versions. For instance 3.3.7 has this:

```
pre{display:block;padding:9.5px;margin:0 0 10px;font-size:13px;line-height:1.42857143;color:#333;word-break:break-all;word-wrap:break-word;background-color:#f5f5f5;border:1px solid #ccc;border-radius:4px}
```

While 4.5.2 has:

```
pre{margin-top:0;margin-bottom:1rem;overflow:auto;-ms-overflow-style:scrollbar}
```

Otherwise I suggest that you use the inspector function of your browser while browsing the site in version 3.x, and focus on a pre tag, then copy the applied styles.

Comment: When I use that 3.3.7 pre css block, it works. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The `<pre>` tag in 3 obviously just has some padding and a border. You can use the utility classes for [border](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/borders/#border) and for [padding](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/spacing/#notation).
The line below appears to give the result you seek.

```
<pre class="p-4 border">
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this bootstrap classes, for my case it looks close enough to bootstrap 3:

```
<pre class="border rounded bg-light">
```

So I don't need custom CSS.